# Updating a textview from the adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have two views one for list and the other one for the header. The list has an item and a checkbox without text. I am trying to update a textview in the header section with the total count of selected items on each checkbox click. But it is not getting updated. Here is my code in the adapter. Can anybody help with a working solution?

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
           .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

   View pview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent,false);
   TextView txtcnt= (TextView) pview.findViewById(R.id.txtcount);
   txtcnt.setText("8"); //This code not updating the textview.
 ........
```

Comment: Provide more info . Is the header is part of list item or its just a single header ? Add item xml and adapter code .

Comment: take a public static variable to set the count and set it to the textview

Comment: Header is a part of another view where the listview is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can update the textview ,lets say your header textview is in activity or fragment class and you are trying to update the header from adapter then make the header textview in your activity or fragment class as public static and access header textview to set values in adapter